# acf.json - can you edit locally?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a weird issue, I am editing a WordPress with advanced custom fields, but I do not have permission to see the plugin, I do have, however, the 'acf.json' file,

is there a possibility I can use this file to create custom fields instead of using the plugin?

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you ask us how to circumvent application permissions? why not the admin to grant you permissions? maybe you're really not supposed to use it...

Comment: sorry - this is not what I meant - if it is permissions issue then I won't use it!